# Fedora 36 boots into emergency mode

Tags: boot, fedora

After installing the latest system updates, my Fedora 36 install fails to boot and runs into emergency mode.

Some facts:

- I can boot normally when selecting the previous kernel version;
- I also got an "NVIDIA not found on Kernel, falling back to noveau" message;
- Unindtalling the NVIDIA driver (through the software ui) didnt fix the issue;
- Disabling secure boot didnt fix the problem;

Current kernel: 5.18.19-200
Working kernel: 5.18.18-200

Edit: boot log

[image]

Found another thread with same problem

https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/os-release-file-not-found/25503/2

Comment: I ran into the same issue yesterday. There is a new kernel update today for 5.19.4-200. Sadly after install and restart picking previous working kernel (5.18.18-200) to be able to boot  and install updates, new kernel has the same issue.

Comment: I was running the old kernel and waiting for updates instead of manually fixing GRUB like the gitlab issue says. Then somehow the old kernels got deleted without notice. I'm just back to Windows, enough waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

**Temporary solution:**
Purge 5.18.19-200, Reinstall Nvidia drivers.
This is not likely to be a problem unless you have a very special system that is very "exposed" on the internet.

Comment: thanks, Ill have a look. I just edited with a boot log

Comment: Note that a text-form log is preferred. Usually available in the files in `/var/log/`

Comment: most important line there is:
Failed to switch root: Specified switch root path '/sysroot' does not seem to be an OS tree. os-release file is missing. I'guess the install failed to find the proper partition to write things?
Which other place should I look at?

Comment: Not nvidia related. Redid the install without anything NVIDIA and problem persisted. Guess Ill just wait until they can publish a decent patch.

Comment: feedback 1 year later
it was some NVIDIA update that broke a grub configuration (boot string).
I did not fix it. I got pissed off and now I use windows.

Comment: With Ubuntu 20.04, the fact that nvidia drivers are using dkms (Dynamic Kernel Module Support) seem to have totally eradicated problems similar to the above.